# How to allow only admins to execute a command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

i am writing following command

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def admins_only_command(ctx, *, args):
    '''do stuff
```

how can i restrict this command to admins only? I tried looking at `ctx.author.roles.role` and it says `@everyone`. How can i check if the given user is an `admin` or not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two ways: by a whitelist of roles using [`has_any_role`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.has_any_role)

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_any_role("Big Cheese", "Medium Cheese")
async def admins_only_command(ctx, *, args):
    '''do stuff'''
```

or by permission using [`has_permissions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.has_permissions)

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def admins_only_command(ctx, *, args):
    '''do stuff'''
```

Both of these decorators are [Checks](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#checks), and will raise some subclass of `CommandError` for you to optionally handle if they fail.