# Discord bot check if the message author has administration rights

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, discord.py

**I'm trying to make a log command that only works when the message author has administrative permissions or more.**
I'm using the **discord.Permission** command for this but when asking if the user has administrative rights **it ONLY asks if the user has the Administrator permission**, when the user has more than really just the Administrator permission it already stops working since the Permission code changes. So in the case of my code I get the message "You do not have the rights to use this command." although I have every single permission
*(This also happens when I only give myself Administrative rights for some reason, maybe it doesn't work because I get extra rights? (owner))*.

Here's the command I'm talking about:

```
elif msg.content == "e.log":
 if msg.author == discord.Permissions.administrator:
        await msg.channel.send("Please define the logging Channel:")
 else:
    await msg.channel.send("You do not have the rights to use this command.")
```

I'd expect to get the message "Please define the logging Channel:" even if I have more permissions than just the Administration permission.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using the `commands` extension?  If so, you can use the `has_permissions` decorator: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51814995/how-to-allow-only-admins-to-execute-a-command/51823516#51823516

Comment: Hey, I'm pretty sure you mean the commands module, I can't use that since it's not avaliable in Python 3.x. I've read that subprocess should be used instead [link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/commands.html#module-commands) but I don't know how to execute a simmilar command in subprocess.

Comment: No, I mean `discord.ext.commands` https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/index.html

Answer (score 0):

The following code is an example, it does nothing if the author does not have administrator, if it has, it executes the stuff

```
@bot.command()
@has_permissions(administrator=True)
```