# How can I make sue only I can use certain commands on my Discord bot? (Python)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

So my Discord bot can now kick people from my server. But right now everyone can use the kick command. And I don't want that. How can I fix this?

This is the code so far:

```
@bot.command(name="kick", aliases=["k"], help= "Kicks specified user from the server.")
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
  await member.send(f"You have been kicked, reason: {reason}")
  await member.kick(reason=reason)
  await ctx.send(f'User {member} has been kicked.')
  embed=discord.Embed(
    title= f"{bot.user} kicked {member}",
    color=bot.embed_color,
    timestamp = datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc)
  )
  embed.set_author(
    name = ctx.author.name,
    icon_url = ctx.author.avatar_url
  )
  embed.set_footer(
  text = bot.footer,
  icon_url = bot.footerimg
  )
  await bot.debug_channel.send(embed = embed)
  print("Sent and embed")
  await ctx.message.add_reaction('✅')
  print("Added a reaction to a message")
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Either use `@commands.has_permissions(Your_Permission=True)` or restrict it to a role `@commands.has_any_role("RoleName")`

Comment: @Dominik where do I add `@commands.has_any_role("RoleName")`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to only let certain users use a command discord.py rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67222398/how-to-only-let-certain-users-use-a-command-discord-py-rewrite)

Comment: @TheFungusAmongUs I don't really understand it. I just want the command to only be able to be usable by admins. I'm having no problems with DM's.

Comment: The title said 'so only I can use', so I linked a post related to that. But for what you're looking for, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51814995/how-to-allow-only-admins-to-execute-a-command) post should help you.

Comment: Next time though, please look up your question. I found these posts simply by pasting the title of your post into the search bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done that before, this answer may help.

First, import the necessary modules first

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions
```

I assume you already set up and defined the bot. Here's the whole code that you should replace with:

```
@bot.command(name="kick", aliases=["k"], help= "Kicks specified user from the server.")
@has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
  await member.send(f"You have been kicked, reason: {reason}")
  await member.kick(reason=reason)
  await ctx.send(f'User {member} has been kicked.')
  embed=discord.Embed(
    title= f"{bot.user} kicked {member}",
    color=bot.embed_color,
    timestamp = datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc)
  )
  embed.set_author(
    name = ctx.author.name,
    icon_url = ctx.author.avatar_url
  )
  embed.set_footer(
  text = bot.footer,
  icon_url = bot.footerimg
  )
  await bot.debug_channel.send(embed = embed)
  print("Sent and embed")
  await ctx.message.add_reaction('✅')
  print("Added a reaction to a message")
```

What I added was simply `@has_permissions(administrator=True)`. The answer you got previously in this post missed the **s** after **permission**, so it should be `@has_permissions` instead of `@has_permission`.

I hope this works! Let me know if you it works!

Answer (score -1):

First import discord.ext.commands if you haven't already.
If you want only admin to be able to kick then add the decorator `@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)` after the command decorator. List of all permissions is here https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Permissions

Side note: discord.py project has officially been discontinued, so I recommend not to use it.

Comment: discord.py actually just came back recently

Comment: If i add `@commands.has_permission(administrator=True)` it give me this error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 71, in <module>
    @commands.has_permission(administrator=True)
AttributeError: module 'discord.ext.commands' has no attribute 'has_permission'`

Comment: that was a mistake on my side. it's has_permissions with an s